# other order of method in route makes blank page

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a little problem ( Laravel 5.0 ) with routing.
When I put this in routes.php

```
Route::get('admin/tags', 'Admin\TagController@index');
Route::get('admin/tags/{id}','Admin\TagController@show');
Route::get('admin/tags/create', 'Admin\TagController@create');
```

last route admin/tags/create show blank page.
but when i change order to ( create 1st )

```
Route::get('admin/tags/create', 'Admin\TagController@create');
Route::get('admin/tags', 'Admin\TagController@index');
Route::get('admin/tags/{id}','Admin\TagController@show');
```

everything is ok and admin/tags/create view showing content.

Answer (score 0):

when the users asks for
/admin/tags/create 
the requested url will also match 
Route::get('admin/tags/{id}','Admin\TagController@show'); 
because it can pars your "create" word as the {id} part of the route definition.
to solve this, you can use some reqular expressions that describe your {id} as an string, consists of numbers 0-9 .